# The meaning of 'otherwise' in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of *otherwise* in this context?

> "using solar power to desalinate water and grow tomatoes in the **otherwise** parched landscape"

Comment: Adverb, definition 2: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=otherwise&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KXHrWKLJOcT48Aed2pOYBQ.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, taha. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question: i this case, you could look at a dictionary, for example the one suggested by @TeacherKSHuang, and see whether any of the suggested meanings would work. If you are still confused, ask a specific question explaining what you don't understand and provide links to your research.

Comment: @JavaLatte - Excellent advice, as usual. However, I'd probably point to a better dictionary than the excerpt displayed by Google. One of my favorites is [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/otherwise), and [Cambridge's](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise?a=british) dictionary is learner-friendly. Of course, these and many more can be easily found if you start at [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=otherwise&ls=a).

Comment: @J.R. Agreed. I generally look at the Oxford and the Cambridge dictionaries, and pick which offers the more appropriate definition for the particular question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, "otherwise" can indicate that the object it's modifying is an exception to a larger rule; in this case, the landscape is parched in general, except for in the area affected by the solar power and desalinated water.  **Basically, it serves to indicate that the aforementioned object is an exception to the larger rule that it would follow under regular circumstances.**